# When to use the word perceive

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, synonyms

When I was reading about the meanings of the word **perceive**, I found that it is used in different ways. For example, sometimes it could mean **understand** but in other contexts it could mean **realize**, so I am a little confused because I do not know if it is exactly *interchangeable* with the words **understand** and **realize** or not.

Comment: It's closely related to the verb *see*. *I see you* has a wide range of meanings, for example. *I see you* could mean I can perceive (hah!) you with my eyes, or I visit you, or I understand you (though normally, that would be just *I see* or *I (can) see what you're trying to say*), among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Perceive** refers to the capacity of **perception** through your senses. You can perceive something through one or more of your senses, that is seeing, smelling, touching, hearing or tasting.

But to perceive something doesn't necessarily imply that you **understand** or **realize** it:

> I can perceive something in the sky but I can't realize what it is.

However, there are instances when you may assimilate the **perception** to an **understanding**, for example definition #2 from [American Heritage Dictinary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perceive):

> 2. To achieve understanding of; apprehend: Einstein perceived that energy and matter are equivalent.